# Появление изображения при выборе input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

При выборе цвета, букет должен меняться на нужный.
Попытался сделать так, вроде должно работать, но не в какую. В чем ошибка или как по-другому можно сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div id="selmimg"><img src="buket-krasniy.png" /></div>
 <div class="cc-selector" id="bess">
     <input id="red" type="radio" name="color" value="red" data-path="buket-krasniy.png" selected />
     <label class="drinkcard-cc red" for="red"></label>
     <input id="white" type="radio" name="color" value="white" data-path="buket-beliy.png" />
     <label class="drinkcard-cc white" for="white"></label>
     <input id="pink" type="radio" name="color" value="pink" data-path="buket-rozoviy.png" />
     <label class="drinkcard-cc pink" for="pink"></label>
 </div>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#bess').change(function(){
            $('#selmimg').find('img:first').attr('src', $('#bess input:selected').attr('data-path'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в получении активного радио инпута.

Вы делаете:

```
$('#bess input:selected')
```

Будет работать:

```
$('#bess input:checked')
```